# Discharged hypotheses in ->Introduction

Tags: lo.logic, natural-deduction

I have a question about page 9 in [Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf).

The given $\rightarrow$Introduction rule says that $A \rightarrow B$ can be deduced from $B$ if the deduction of $B$ contains an arbitrary number of $A$s (0 or more).  How can this be true if there are zero $A$s in the deduction of $B$?

Comment: Is this a research-level question (I believe it's not)?

Comment: Not really, but the connection with relevance logic that this question unwittingly hints at is certainly interesting, albeit also known.

Comment: this is why we need theory B experts here :)

Answer (score 21):

Dave Clarke's answer basically says it all: this is the standard convention in classical and constructive mathematics.  Nonetheless, your objection is the source of a century-old subdiscipline of philosophical logic called "[relevance logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/)", which can be seen as rejecting the axiom p → (q → p) -- or in terms of natural deduction, rejecting precisely this ability to use a hypothesis zero times, or equivalently in terms of sequent calculus, rejecting the structural rule of **weakening**. Reconsidering other structural rules/axioms leads more generally to [substructural logics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-substructural/), which have found applications in linguistics and theoretical computer science.  (One important example, linear logic, is mentioned in the appendix to Proofs and Types.)

Answer (score 20):

Think about the hypothesis: *It rains in Belgium*. This is true. Assume that the proof of this fact does not contain the assumption *Cows eat grass*. What the $\to$ introduction rule states is that I can nonetheless conclude *Cows eat grass* $\to$ *It rains in Belgium*. Classically, this is true whether or not *Cows eat grass* is true. Constructively, if I have a proof of *Cows eat grass*, I can simply throw it away and return the previous proof of *It rains in Belgium*, as implicitly this is what the meaning of $A\to B$ is: it takes proofs of $A$ and converts them into proofs of $B$.

Comment: I checked on the web. It's not raining in Belgium.

Comment: @Andrej: Logic or no logic. The web's wrong. It was raining when I came home and it's raining now. I dare not say that it's always raining, lest we venture into modal territory.

Answer (score 0):

It is the case when B is not derived from any previous rule/axiom; that is, B is an axiom/tautology itself.

Comment: this is not correct.